# Convert max integer to floating point without precision loss

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

I have a following snippet which I used to try to test if a precision loss occurs if I convert a max integer to a `double`:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main () noexcept
{
    uint64_t ui64{std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()};
    constexpr auto max_precision{std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 + 1}; 
    std::cout << "ui64 " << std::setprecision(max_precision) << std::boolalpha << ui64 << "\n\n";

    double f64 = static_cast<double>(ui64);
    uint64_t ui64_cast_back = static_cast<uint64_t>(f64);
    std::cout << "sizeof(f64): " << sizeof(double) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f64 = " << f64 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ui64_cast_back matches original value? " << (ui64_cast_back == ui64) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ui64_cast_back = " << ui64_cast_back << std::endl;
}
```

When I build this for the custom platform of my project (not available on Compiler Explorer) I get the following output:

```
ui64 18446744073709551615

sizeof(f64): 8
f64 = 18446744073709551616
ui64_cast_back matches original value? true
ui64_cast_back = 18446744073709551615
```

Off by one error when printing the `double` value seems to suggest that there is a precision loss. Yet when casting back, the original value is retrieved. Is it possible that the off by one is caused by the IO streams implementation when printing, or the printing can be considered a proof of precision loss?

Comment: What happens if you print more digits in the double? I would expect anything on the order of 2^53 to have no precision loss.

Comment: Impossible, floating point is not precise enough. Both types take 8 bytes in memory, but the floating point uses some of those bits for exponential so it cannot represent all integer values precisely (specifically not the larger ones). Watch this [Tom Scott on Floating Point Numbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0).

Comment: A `double` has 53-bits of *significand*.  A `uint64_t` has 64-bits of integer values.  64 > 53.  A `uint64_t` that is greater than `1ULL << 53` won't fit in a double precisely (except at specific exact values).

Comment: `long double` and `double` are different types. On some platforms they have same representations, on some others different sizes. Fix this to prevent cross platform surprises.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like `double` on your platform is [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

There is no `18446744073709551615` in that format. The two values closest are:

```cpp
18446744073709549568  // The double below
18446744073709551615  // Your integer (not exactly representable)
18446744073709551616  // The double above
```

So `double f64 = static_cast<double>(ui64);` rounds the value to the closest double (the one above). There is no way to prevent "precision loss" since it physically can't be represented. (Consider that there are 2^64 `int64_t` values, and at most 2^64 double values).

You should notice you get the same results for `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()-1` or `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()-2` etc. because they also round to the same value.

When you do the cast back, you have undefined behaviour because the double is now too large to fit in an int64_t. Your machine seems to simply return the largest int64_t if the double is too large.

Comment: No, I realize that in general there will be a precision loss. I just thought that maybe that exact value had the correct representation as a 64 bit float. In any case, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Max ui64 is 2^64-1

The nearest FP double representation of that number using a 53 bit mantissa and 11 bit exponent is 2^64. Casting 2^64 as a double (bigger than max_uint64) back to uint64 saturates and returns the highest value that a ui64 type can represent namely 2^64-1

Try it again with max_uint64/2, max_uint64-1000 and /4. Only when you get down to 2^53 can a uint64 be exactly represented in a 64 bit double precision variable. If you have access to long double 80 bit reals (a la x87) with 64 bit mantissa and 16 bit exponent then your problems are solved! That can hold a 64bit uint.

Comment: On msvc `long double` has same representation as `double`. I guess they were too woried about alignment/padding.